# 'videlicet': How did "it is permissible to see" semantically shift to mean "that is to say"?

Tags: etymology, english

How did 1 beneath semantically shift to 2? [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/viz.?ref=etymonline_crossreference):

> #### viz.
>
> 1530s, abbreviation of videlicet **[2.]** "that is to say, to wit, namely" (mid-15c.),
>   from Latin videlicet, contraction of videre licet **[1.]** "it is permissible to see,"
>   from videre "to see" (see [vision](https://www.etymonline.com/word/vision?ref=etymonline_crossreference)) + licet "it is allowed," third person singular present indicative of licere "be allowed" (see [licence](https://www.etymonline.com/word/licence?ref=etymonline_crossreference)).
>   The -z- is not a letter, but originally a twirl, representing the usual Medieval Latin shorthand symbol for the ending -et. "In reading aloud usually rendered by 'namely.' " [OED]

The semantic shift for ['scilicet'](https://www.etymonline.com/word/scilicet) looks similar, but I also don't understand it.

Comment: In spoken English a thoughtful person, gathering their thoughts might say, "I was watching, let's see, twelve or fifteen goldfinches eating berries." Videlicet must be very close to parenthetic 'let's see;' and similar in meaning if *licet* =allow=let.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"it is allowed to see" -> "you can see" -> "you can notice" -> "something worth noticing" -> "to wit, namely"